# Return string when division result is zero

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, case, coalesce

I have an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT 
u.id,
tu.score/(CASE tu.mo_count  WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE tu.mo_count END) AS score_avg
FROM tournament_userscore tu
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = tu.user_id
WHERE tournament_id = 1
ORDER BY tu.score DESC
```

When `tu.mo_count` is zero, Null has been replaced instead of zero. How can I set a string like `'EMPTY'` for this line:

```
tu.score/(CASE tu.mo_count  WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE tu.mo_count END) AS score_avg
```

I mean when division result is ***zero*** or ***empty***, I want to return "**anything**" string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the `CASE`-statement outside:

```
SELECT 
u.id,
CASE WHEN tu.mo_count = 0 THEN 'EMPTY' ELSE (tu.score/tu.mo_count)::text END as score_avg
FROM tournament_userscore tu
INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = tu.user_id
WHERE tournament_id = 1
ORDER BY tu.score DESC
```

Comment: thanks dude. works fine. can you explain ::text little more for me?

Comment: All of the values in a column need to have the same type, so the `::text` casts the ratio into text. Trivial example: `select 'foo' union select 42;`

Comment: I found it: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-character.html thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use NULLIF and COALESCE if you don't want to use a CASE:

```
SELECT 
  u.id,
  COALESCE(tu.score/NULLIF(tu.mo_count, 0), 0) AS score_avg
FROM tournament_userscore tu
  INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = tu.user_id
WHERE 
  tournament_id = 1
ORDER BY 
  tu.score DESC;
```